# In python, how do I expose some command from my distutils package?

Tags: python, installation, pip, distutils, setup.py

After installing django:

```
pip install django
```

I can immediately write:

```
django-admin.py startproject project
```

And `django-admin.py` is somehow known to my system.

I'm developing small webserver and distribute is using PIP - what should I put in my `setup.py` to expose my `runserver.py` file system-wide in the same manner as Django does?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [scripts](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-scripts) keyword to setup. For example:

```
setup(...,
      scripts=['django_admin.py']
      )
```

The script is required to be executable.

In some cases, an alternative is to specify a function in a module that should be an [entry_point](http://guide.python-distribute.org/creation.html#entry-points)

```
setup(...,

    entry_points={
        'console_scripts':
             ['myscript = my.package.scripts:main'],
    }
}
```